# Selecionar dados do último arquivo do banco e selecionar dados do arquivo da hora anterior ao último. Comparar Dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Após buscar dois arquivos carregados, vou na tabela para comparar os dados dentro deles

Entre `8: 50 e 23: 50` (com intervalo de uma em uma hora) ele executa uma checagem em um arquivo desse banco que chamo de Busca Hora com o Padrão estabelecido. Ele procura o arquivo mais recente e o arquivo da hora anterior e compara.

Dentro desse arquivo tenho a tabela com os campos

```
        dtt_data    dtt_hora    int_paradas flt_base    vch_classe_tarifaria    flt_value   vch_classe_tarifaria_1  dtt_data_captura    vch_nome_arquivo
    7/19/2017   10:55:00    1   788.9   JOOQDGZ 788.9   JOOQDGZ 7/12/2017   BUSCA_HORA_201707122000_out_ow.csv
    7/19/2017   10:55:00    1   788.9   JOOQDGZ 788.9   JOOQDGZ 7/12/2017   BUSCA_HORA_201707122000_out_ow.csv
    7/19/2017   6:05:00 1   788.9   JOOQDGZ 788.9   JOOQDGZ 7/12/2017   BUSCA_HORA_201707122000_out_ow.csv
    7/19/2017   2:00:00 1   594.9   PPOSDGZ 594.9   PPOSDGZ 7/12/2017   
BUSCA_HORA_201707122000_out_ow.csv
```

Então comparar e trazer três resultados:

New

Trazer resultado que existem no arquivo Agora e que não existiam no arquivo Anterior de uma hora atrás

Not Found

Trazer resultado que existem no arquivoAnterior de uma hora atrás  e que não existiam no arquivo Agora

Modified

Trazer resultado dos dois de tudo que foi modificado

Fiz algo mais ou menos assim:

```
Select * from #Agora AG
        Left Join #Agora1 AG1 ON AG.vch_classe_tarifaria_1 = AG1.vch_classe_tarifaria_1


Select * from #Agora1 AG
        Left Join #Agora AG1 ON AG.vch_classe_tarifaria_1 = AG1.vch_classe_tarifaria_1


Select * from #Agora    
except  
Select * from #Agora1
```

Gostaria de ajuda para montar as três consultas

Comment: para seleccionares os 2 últimos podes ordenar por descendência e limitar  `SELECT * FROM tb_arquivo_processado ORDER BY dtt_data_insercao DESC LIMIT 2;`

Comment: Não funcionava para mim, o LIMIT

Comment: A `query` inicial já faz o que você deseja. Provavelmente seu `WHERE` está sumindo com alguns registros, não?

Comment: É possível, não consegui acertar para que traga o ultimo arquivo e o da hora anterior no Where

Comment: @13dev, 13 :) LIMIT é usado para MySQL, sql server usar TOP.

Comment: @Thais, certamente seu select esta fazendo filtro pelo nome do arquivo WHERE [vch_nome_arquivo] like 'G3_OW_BUSCA_HORA_%' sua amostra de dados não tem arquivo que comecem com assa string.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza `"todos estamos aqui para aprender, portanto seja amistoso e prestativo!"` - **SO** ,erro meu.

Comment: @13dev, não leve para um lado ruim, só foi uma dica.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não foi um erro na query, foi só na hora de dar o exemplo aqui, já editei

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza claro que não, obrigado pela a informação!

Comment: @13dev tentei pelo TOP, mas não me atende. Não consigo pegar os dois arquivos e comparar os dados deles, o que tem em um, e o que tem no outro. E tudo que for igual, mostrando numa tabela

Comment: Editei um pouco mais, tentando esclarecer um poucos mais rs

Comment: @Thais, não tem como te ajudar sem saber o que você tem em sua tabela, você faz alguns filtros no seu select como `WHERE [vch_nome_arquivo] like 'BUSCA_HORA_%'` e 
`AND [fk_int_status] IN ('2','4')` esse `AND` não tem amostra dos dados para sabemos o que pode ou não esta trazendo e o `AND [dtt_data_captura] = '2017-07-12'` esta comparando um campo datime ??? com uma string ??  isso pode causa falhas no seu select.

Comment: Acabei de postar os campos que tenho nas tabelas: [vch_od] ,[vch_empresa] ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [dtt_data], 101) AS DATE ,[vch_classe_tarifaria] ,[vch_numeros] ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),[dtt_hora],108) AS DTIME ,[flt_base] ,[dtt_geracao_ql2] ,[dtt_data_captura] ,[vch_nome_arquivo] ,[vch_tipo_arquivo]

Comment: E não estou comparando não, apenas estava colocando no Where a data que tenho certeza de que tem dado, para conseguir visualizar se funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue exemplo abaixo utilizando SQL Server 2008 R2, com base no site oficial da microsoft:

```
WITH TABELA AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT HireDate 
FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[HumanResources].[Employee]
)
SELECT TOP 2 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY HireDate DESC) AS Row, HireDate
FROM TABELA
ORDER BY HireDate DESC
```

[Referencia.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)